# Sitecore Rebuilding Index End Event Programatically

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I'm using Sitecore 8.0 and trying to do a Refresh or Rebuild Index programmatically, I just want to know if there's an event where I will know that the job of rebuilding or refreshing is already done, so I can trigger my custom code, I've tried using "Thread.Sleep" but it didn't work as expected.

Here's the sample code that I made:

```
 searchIndex.Rebuild(Sitecore.ContentSearch.IndexingOptions.ForcedIndexing);
 Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

Let me know if you need any other information. Thanks.

Comment: From what I remember, `Rebuild` method is executed synchronously. Which means that your code will not proceed to the next line until rebuilding is completed. Or am I wrong? You may want to check `Crawling` log - there should be `Full Rebuild Started` and `Full Rebuild Ended` messages there.

Comment: I've tried looking at the crawling log but I don't see any Full Rebuild messages even at the old logs.